# How to generate random 2D points without replacement in matlab

Tags: matlab

Assume that we can generate numbers as follows:

```
% Generating random points
NP = 30; % number of points
x = randi([0 10],1,NP);
y = randi([0 10],1,NP);
P = [x;y]; % group the points as columns in a matrix
```

finding repeated points could be done using loops or if-statements but is there any better solution?

Comment: Do you want to keep or get rid of duplicates? Look into [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html?refresh=true) with the `rows` option.

Comment: @Suever I want to replace them with new random points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, I would simply create all permutations of `x` and `y` and then randomly select `NP` of these permutations.

```
NP = 30;

% All permutations of X and Y
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(0:10, 0:10);

% Grab NP of these permutations
indices = randperm(numel(xx), NP);

% Construct P from just these permutations
P = [xx(indices); yy(indices)].';
```

And just to verify that they are in fact unique.

```
isequal(P, unique(P, 'rows', 'stable'))

    1
```

Comment: @Remy Any reason you unselected it as an answer?